# Form FormClosing event not firing if a designer created timer has been defined and is running

Tags: c#, .net, windows, timer, formclosing

If I try to right-click close the minimised form application or using task manager applications tab to end the process the FormClosing event does not trigger while a timer is  defined and is running/enabled.

```
//Extract from Form designer.cs:
....
private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1;
....
this.timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
this.timer1.Interval = 5000;
....
this.timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
......
this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.FormSI_Load);
this.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(this.FormSI_FormClosing);


//Extract from form.cs:
namespace namespace
{
    public partial class FormSI : Form
    {
       .....
       public FormSaturnInterface()
       {
          InitializeComponent();
          ......
          timer1.Interval = intTimerIntervalms;
          //timer1.Enabled = true; //FormClosing event not triggered if timer1 enabled
          timer1.Enabled = false;  //FormClosing event triggered if timer1 not enabled
          ........
          private void FormSI_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
                  MessageBox.Show("Load Event triggered["+ e.ToString() + "]", "Load Event triggered", MessageBoxButtons.OK); //Load event always triggered with or without timer1 enabled
          }

          private void FormSI_FormClosing(Object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
          {
               //e.Cancel = true; //stops app/form closing
              timer1.Stop();
              System.Text.StringBuilder messageBoxCS = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
              messageBoxCS.AppendFormat("{0} = {1}", "CloseReason", e.CloseReason);
              messageBoxCS.AppendLine();
              messageBoxCS.AppendFormat("{0} = {1}", "Cancel", e.Cancel);
              messageBoxCS.AppendLine();
              MessageBox.Show(messageBoxCS.ToString(), "FormClosing Event");
          }
          ........
```

I do not wish to stop/disable the timer until an attempt is made to close/end the application yet still want the Formclosing event to trigger. What are possible solutions to this scenario? Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Please note that the FormSI.designer.cs already contains this code:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Disposing", "Disposing", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

This Dispose method is called as is the Form_FormClosing event when the timer1 is disabled, but neither appear to being called when the timer1 is enabled and in this case end task is the only way of terminating the app/form. Could it be the thread is too busy with the time to process the Close request? If so how can one cause the thread to be periodically interrupted to allow it to service the close request?

The issue, was that the app could not be closed in an orderly fashion allowing a user to be prompted to save data for example or did they really mean to close the app. The issue was to do with the timer being caught in a loop when certain databases were not available and therefore no other messages/events could be processed by the single thread. As soon as the timer exited from the loop, by either timing out or reaching the required database all queued messages / events were then processed correctly. Thank you to all respondents for the time and feedback this helps the thought processes and allows you to thing of alternative reasons for certain behaviors. :)

Comment: What's the need to disable the timer when the whole application is being torn down.  It's not like it's going to keep running once the entire process ceases to exist.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was to do with the timer being caught in a loop when certain databases were not available and therefore no other messages/events could be processed by the single thread. As soon as the timer exited from the loop, by either timing out or reaching the required database all queued messages / events were then processed correctly. Thank you to all respondents for the time and feedback this helps the thought processes and allows you to thing of alternative reasons for certain behaviors. :)